# Unable to slice pandas dataframe (with date as key) using date as string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I'm generating an empty dataframe with a series of dates as the index. Data will be added to the dataframe at a later point.

```
cbd=pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2017,01,02),end=pd.datetime(2017,01,30),period=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=['Test1','Test2'],index=cbd)

df.head()
           Test1 Test2
2017-01-02   NaN   NaN
2017-01-03   NaN   NaN
2017-01-04   NaN   NaN
2017-01-05   NaN   NaN
2017-01-06   NaN   NaN
```

A few slicing methods don't seem to work. The following returns a KeyError:

```
df['2017-01-02']
```

However any of the following work:

```
df['2017-01-02':'2017-01-02']
df.loc['2017-01-02']
```

What am I missing here? Why doesn't the first slice return a result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Dual behavior of `[]` in `df[]`

- When you don't use `:` inside `[]`, then the value(s) inside it will be considered as column(s).
- And when you use `:` inside `[]`, then the value(s) inside it will be considered as row(s).

#### Why the dual nature?

Because most of the time people want to slice the rows instead of slicing the columns.

So they decided that `x` and `y` in `df[x:y]` should correspond to rows,

and `x` in `d[x]` or `x`, `y` in `df[[x,y]]` should correspond to column(s).

#### Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
                                 index = ['A','B','C'], columns = ['A','B','C'])
print df
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
A  1  2  3
B  1  2  3
C  1  2  3
```

Now when you do `df['B']`, it can mean 2 things:

- Take the 2nd index `B` and give you the 2nd row `1 2 3`

  ```
                   OR
  ```
- Take the 2nd column `B` and give you the 2nd column `2 2 2`.

So in order to resolve this conflict and keep it unambiguous `df['B']` will always mean that you want the column `'B'`, if there is no such column then it will throw an Error.

#### Why does `df['2017-01-02']` fails?

It will search for a column `'2017-01-02'`, Because there is no such column, it throws an error.

#### Why does `df.loc['2017-01-02']` works then?

Because `.loc[]` has  syntax of `df.loc[row,column]` and you can leave out the column if you will, as in your case, it simply means `df.loc[row]`

Answer (score 4):

There is difference, because use different approaches:

For select one row is necessary `loc`:

> df['2017-01-02']

[Docs - partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing):

> **Warning**
>
> The following selection will raise a **KeyError**; otherwise this selection methodology would be inconsistent with other selection methods in pandas (as this is not a slice, nor does it resolve to one):

```
dft['2013-1-15 12:30:00']
```

> To select a single row, use .loc

```
In [74]: dft.loc['2013-1-15 12:30:00']
Out[74]: 
A    0.193284
Name: 2013-01-15 12:30:00, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['2017-01-02':'2017-01-02']
```

This is pure [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing):

> This type of slicing will work on a `DataFrame` with a **DateTimeIndex** as well. Since the partial string selection is a form of label slicing, the endpoints **will be included**. This would include matching times on an included date.

Comment: I found this documentation a bit inconsistent. They were able to access the values corresponding to index: ts['1/31/2011'] (which unless I'm missing something, seems very close to what I'm doing) - is it because ts is a Series rather than DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is difference between selecting Series ad Daraframe.

Answer (score 1):

First I have updated your test data (just for info) as it returns an 'invalid token' error. Please see changes here:

```
cbd=pd.date_range(start='2017-01-02',end='2017-01-30',period=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=['Test1','Test2'],index=cbd)
```

Now looking at the first row:

```
In[1]:

df.head(1)

Out[1]:
          Test1 Test2
2017-01-02  NaN NaN
```

And then trying the initial slicing approach yields this error:

```
In[2]:    

df['2017-01-02']

Out[2]:

KeyError: '2017-01-02'
```

Now try this using the `column` name:

```
In[3]:    

df.columns

Out[3]:

Index(['Test1', 'Test2'], dtype='object')

In[4]:
```

We try 'Test1':

```
df['Test1']
```

And get the `NaN` output from this column.

```
Out[4]:

2017-01-02    NaN
2017-01-03    NaN
2017-01-04    NaN
2017-01-05    NaN
```

So the format you are using is designed to be used on the `column` name unless you use this format `df['2017-01-02':'2017-01-02']`.

The [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) state "The following selection will raise a KeyError; otherwise this selection methodology would be inconsistent with other selection methods in pandas (as this is not a slice, nor does it resolve to one)".

So as you correctly identified, [DataFrame.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is a label based indexer which  yields the output you are looking for:

```
 In[5]:
df.loc['2017-01-02']

 Out[5]:

Test1    NaN
Test2    NaN
Name: 2017-01-02 00:00:00, dtype: object
```